# Python: Replace "dumb quotation marks" with “curly ones” in a string

Tags: python, string, typography

I have a string like this:

## "But that gentleman," looking at Darcy, "seemed to think the country was nothing at all."

I want this output:

## “But that gentleman,” looking at Darcy, “seemed to think the country was nothing at all.”

Likewise, dumb single quotes should be converted to their curly equivalents. [Read about the typographic rules here if you are interested.](http://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html)

My guess is that this has been solved before but I can't find a library or script to do it. [SmartyPants](http://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/) (Perl) is the mother of all libraries to do this and there is a [python port](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/smartypants). But its output are HTML entities: `&#x201C;But that gentleman,&#x201D;` I just want a plain string with curly quotes. Any ideas?

**Update:**

I solved it as suggested by Padraig Cunningham:

1. Use smartypants to make the typographic corrections
2. Use `HTMLParser().unescape` to convert the HTML entities back to Unicode

This approach may be problematic if your input text contains HTML entities that you wish not to convert but in my case it's ok.

**End of Update**

*Can the input be trusted?*

The input can only be trusted so far. The string could contain a non-closed double quote: `"But be that gentleman, looking at Dary`. It could also contain a non-closed single quote: `'But be that gentleman, looking at Dary`. Finally, it could contain a single-quote that is meant to be an apostrophe: `Don't go there.`

I have already implemented an alogrithm that tries to close these lost quotes correctly, so this is not part of the question. For completeness, here is the code that closes lost quotes:

```
quotationMarkDictionary = [{
    'start': '"',
    'end': '"',
    },{
    'start': '“',
    'end': '”',
    },{
    'start': '\'',
    'end': '\'',
    },{
    'start': '‘',
    'end': '’'
    },{
    'start': '(',
    'end': ')'
    },{
    'start': '{',
    'end': '}'
    },{
    'start': '[',
    'end': ']'
    }]

'''If assumedSentence has quotation marks (single, double, …) and the 
number of opening quotation marks is larger than the number of closing    
quotation marks, append a closing quotation mark at the end of the 
sentence. Likewise, add opening quotation marks to the beginning of the 
sentence if there are more closing marks than opening marks.'''
for quotationMark in quotationMarkDictionary:
  numberOpenings = assumedSentence['sentence'].count(quotationMark['start'])
  numberClosings = assumedSentence['sentence'].count(quotationMark['end'])
  # Are the opening and closing marks the same? ('Wrong' marks.) Then just make sure there is an even number of them
  if quotationMark['start'] is quotationMark['end'] and numberOpenings % 2 is not 0:
    # If sentence starts with this quotation mark, put the new one at the end
    if assumedSentence['sentence'].startswith(quotationMark['start']):
      assumedSentence['sentence'] += quotationMark['end']
    else:
      assumedSentence['sentence'] = quotationMark['end'] + assumedSentence['sentence']
  elif numberOpenings > numberClosings:
    assumedSentence['sentence'] += quotationMark['end']
  elif numberOpenings < numberClosings:
     assumedSentence['sentence'] = quotationMark['start'] + assumedSentence['sentence']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How much do you trust your input? Do the quotes always correctly come in pairs?

Comment: Here you go - https://gist.github.com/davidtheclark/5521432

Comment: @hashcode55 This produces HTML entities, not plain text.

Comment: @user1582024 I added information to the post regarding your questions.

Comment: the re.sub function supports a callback for the replacement, where you can do the % 2 stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  `HTMLParser` to unescape the html entities returned from smartypants:

```
In [32]: from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

In [33]: s = "&#x201C;But that gentleman,&#x201D;"

In [34]: print HTMLParser().unescape(s)
“But that gentleman,”
In [35]: HTMLParser().unescape(s)
Out[35]: u'\u201cBut that gentleman,\u201d'
```

To avoin encoding errors, you should either use `io.open` when opening the file and specify `encoding="the_encoding"` or decode the strings to unicode:

```
 In [11]: s
Out[11]: '&#x201C;But that gentleman,&#x201D;\xe2'

In [12]: print  HTMLParser().unescape(s.decode("latin-1"))
“But that gentleman,”â
```

Comment: Good idea, but I get an error. The string has been read from a .txt file before.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bildlich/Development/textfiles-to-mongodb/textfiles-to-mongodb.py", line 173, in <module>
    assumedSentences.extend(fileToSentenceList(textFilesDirectory + filename))
  File "/Users/bildlich/Development/textfiles-to-mongodb/textfiles-to-mongodb.py", line 147, in fileToSentenceList
    numberOpenings = assumedSentence['sentence'].count(quotationMark['start'])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: OK, so it is latin-1 encoded data? basically you are trying to concatenate an ascii string to a latin-1 encode string, you sould use unicode everywhere and encode to  str if required.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I solved it by A) making sure that the input text is encoded with UTF-8 using io.open and B) encoding the quotationMark['start'] in UTF-8 as well.

Comment: I added the solution to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question was originally asked, Python smartypants has gained [an option](https://pythonhosted.org/smartypants/reference.html#smartypants._Attr.u) for directly outputting the replaced characters in Unicode:

> u = 256
>
> Output Unicode characters instead of numeric character references, for example, from `&#8220;` to left double quotation mark (`“`) (U+201C).

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest possible use case there is no need for regular expressions:

```python
quote_chars_counts = {
    '"': 0,
    "'": 0,
    "`": 0
}


def to_smart_quotes(s):
    output = []

    for c in s:
        if c in quote_chars_counts.keys():
            replacement = (quote_chars_counts[c] % 2 == 0) and '“' or '”'
            quote_chars_counts[c] = quote_chars_counts[c] + 1
            new_ch = replacement
        else:
            new_ch = c
        output.append(new_ch)

    return ''.join(output)
```

If needed, it's trivial to modify to pull replacements from a replacement map rather than using literals.

Answer (score 0):

Glancing through the documentation, it *looks* like you're stuck with `.replace` on top of the smartypants:

```
smartypants(r'"smarty" \"pants\"').replace('&#x201C;', '“').replace('&#x201D;', '”')
```

Might read better if you alias the magic strings, though:

```
html_open_quote = '&#x201C;'
html_close_quote = '&#x201D;'
smart_open_quote = '“'
smart_close_quote = '”'
smartypants(r'"smarty" \"pants\"') \
    .replace(html_open_quote, smart_open_quote)  \
    .replace(html_close_quote, smart_close_quote)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you suggest to use smartypants to get HTML entities and then decode these entities back to plain text?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming good input, this can be done using regular expressions:

```
# coding=utf8
import re
sample = '\'Sample Text\' - "But that gentleman," looking at Darcy, "seemed to think the \'country\' was nothing at all." \'Don\'t convert here.\''
print re.sub(r"(\s|^)\'(.*?)\'(\s|$)", r"\1‘\2’\3", re.sub(r"\"(.*?)\"", r"“\1”", sample))
```

Output:

```
‘Sample Text’ - “But that gentleman,” looking at Darcy, “seemed to think the ‘country’ was nothing at all.” ‘Don't convert here.’
```

I am separating out single quotes here by assuming they either are at the beginning/end of a line or has white space around them.